# MIME Type is changing my file extension

Tags: ios, ios8, mime, uti

I'm working on an app that allows files to be opened from both the email application Apple provides, and the web. The problem is when I email myself a file, the extension clearly shows it's a `.gfp` file. But the minute I download it to my computer it turns into a `.json` file. The `.gfp` file **is** using JSON to organize the data, but it's not supposed to be a `.json` file. I understand that it's the MIME type screwing it up, but I can't leave the MIME type nil, meaning I'm stuck with a preexisting filetype. How do I keep it a `.gfp` file no matter where it goes?

Code:

`[mailer addAttachmentData:jsonData mimeType:@"application/json" fileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.gfp", objectName.stringThing]];`

I've tried changing the `application/json` to something like a little more broad like `text/plain` but then it morphs into a `.txt` file when transferred to a computer.